# How to execute a large futures order?

Tags: futures, order-execution

I am currently trading futures products on some contracts that have low volumes. More accurately, the volumes of working orders in the book are fairly light. I am trying to execute a relatively large order that could move the market. I would like to break the order up to prevent this but I am unsure of the best algorithm to do it. I know there are iceberg orders but is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct that large orders should be algorithmically broken-up. Perhaps the most straightforward algo is the [VWAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VWAP) (volume-weighted average price), which most brokers offer. Since a VWAP is easy to compute, the trading details are often transparent to the user.

There are more sophisticated algos, like [Arrival Price](http://www.itg.com/news_events/papers/implementation_shortfall.pdf), though not every broker offers these. Here's a list of common [broker algos](http://www.barx.com/futures/algorithmic/index.html).

In general, refrain from submitting a standard market order for a large number of contracts and you should be alright.

Answer (score 7):

For reference, note that execution strategies for some types of futures contracts can be very different from equities. An example are Interest Rate Futures, e.g. [here](http://market-microstructure.institutlouisbachelier.org/presentations/Special%20Microstructural%20Features%20of%20Interest%20Rate%20Futures%20-%20Almgren.pdf).

The main reason lies in microstructure differences. For some more details see the [white paper](http://quantitativebrokers.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/theRollReport.pdf) "US Treasury Futures Roll Microstructure Basics" by Quantitative Brokers (I have no affiliation with QB). Very briefly:

- Traders that don't want to take delivery roll over their positions,
- The matching algo for Treasury spread contracts is “Split FIFO/Pro-Rata.” Fills are allocated so that a percentage of every order is filled either FIFO or pro-rata.

Few consequences of the “Split FIFO/Pro-Rata” matching are:

1. The optimal strategy is to oversize limit orders;
2. Marketable limit orders are attractive (new top order is filled with FIFO);
3. Empirically there are rapid variations in order size.

Comment: Great link, could you please summarize the relevant portion for this question?

Comment: @TalFishman: I added premises and findings.